# How to unwind array of object fields into array of strings in same field in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure:

```
{
    "user_id": "102",
    "roles": [{
        "name": "superuser"
    }, {
        "name": "admin"
    }, {
        "name": "account_admin"
    }]
}
```

And I need to unwind into the following result:

```
{
    "user_id": "102290863723817866607",
    "roles": [
        0: "superuser",
        1: "gsuite_admin",
        2: "account_admin"
    ]
}
```

I can't quite figure out how to stage the aggregation pipeline to get this result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `$project`compined with a `$map` to select the name from your role`s object:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "roles": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$roles",
          "as": "role",
          "in": "$$role.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```